# DNS query timed out looking up A for mydomain

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, plesk

I am try to use let's Encrypt on Plesk and error 400 appears with `[Detail: DNS problem: query timed out looking up A for mydomain][1]`

Comment: does your domain (A) point to the proper IP?

Comment: yes , I am sure for (A)

Comment: can your server resolve the domain?

Comment: domain booked from name.com and I change nameserver to my hosting , name.com say there is not any problem , and my hosting support say also !!!!

Comment: There are two thing: If the error is coming from Plesk, than you local machine, where Plesk is running can not resolv the A Record. If the Error is coming fom LetsEncrypt directly than LE cant resolv the A Record. As a quick and dirty workarround you could use cloudflare meanwhile..

Comment: Thank you for your help